# Two tooltips/dailog when clicking on marker @react-google-maps/api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, next.js13, react-google-maps-api

Consider:

[image]

When I click on the marker, it shows two tooltips/dialog. I am using "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.19.2" in [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) TypeScript.
I am trying to show the tooltip when I click on a marker in this package. The first tooltip is blank, and the second tooltip contains my content. I am using the following code:

```
import {
  GoogleMap,
  InfoWindow,
  LoadScript,
  MarkerF,
  Marker,
} from '@react-google-maps/api';

const containerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '500px',
};

const markers = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Chicago, Illinois',
    position: { lat: 41.881832, lng: -87.623177 },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Denver, Colorado',
    position: { lat: 39.739235, lng: -104.99025 },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Los Angeles, California',
    position: { lat: 34.052235, lng: -118.243683 },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'New York, New York',
    position: { lat: 40.712776, lng: -74.005974 },
  },
];
const MapComponent: FC= () => {
  const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState<number>();
  const handleActiveMarker = (marker: number) => {
    if (marker === activeMarker) {
      return undefined;
    }
    setActiveMarker(marker);
  };
  const handleOnLoad = (map: google.maps.Map) => {
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    markers.forEach(({ position }) => bounds.extend(position));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };

  return (
    <LoadScript googleMapsApiKey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY!}>
      <GoogleMap
        onLoad={handleOnLoad}
        mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
        zoom={10}
      >
        {markers.map(({ id, name, position }) => (
          <MarkerF
            key={id}
            position={position}
            onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(id)}
          >
            {activeMarker === id ? (
              <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(undefined)}>
                <div key={id}>{name}</div>
              </InfoWindow>
            ) : null}
          </MarkerF>
        ))}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};
```

This code works correctly for the first tooltip, but the second tooltip is not displayed.
How can I show only one tooltip when I click on this or how can I hide one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use `<InfoWindowF />` component instead of the `<InfoWindow />` component since you are also using the functional based `<MarkerF />` component

The `react-google-maps/api` library have 2 different types of components,

1. Class Based - The components without "F" at the end. *e.g. `<Marker />`*
2. Function Based - The components with "F" at the end. *e.g. `<MarkerF />`*

see github repo for more information: https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api/tree/master/packages/react-google-maps-api

So after playing around with your code, I found out that you were still using the class based Info Window component in a function based Marker component. This could have caused some compatibility issue. So what I did to fix this is I just properly imported the **InfoWindowF**,

```
import {
  GoogleMap,
  InfoWindowF,
  LoadScript,
  MarkerF,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";
```

Then change the Info Window component you use inside the Marker component into something like this,

```
{markers.map(({ id, name, position }) => (
  <MarkerF
    key={id}
    position={position}
    onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(id)}
  >
    {activeMarker === id ? (
      <InfoWindowF onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(undefined)}>
        <div key={id}>{name}</div>
      </InfoWindowF>
    ) : null}
  </MarkerF>
))}
```

Then everything should be fine:

[image: Working sample screenshot]

Here's a codesandbox link if you want to see it for yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-duplicate-stack-overflow-fix-pmcscz

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great! If this answer helped, feel free to upvote or accept this answer so that others who encounters the same issue as you would be able to see this better and help them also.